# gulp-imagemin poor compression rate

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I've run the images on my site through `gulp-imagemin` in order to compress them and decrease its size. I've used several plugins available with `gulp-imagemin`. The definition of my 'compress' task below:

```
gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('themes/rubbish_taxi/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant(), jpegtran(), optipng(), gifsicle()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/rubbish_taxi/images/dist'));
});
```

Unfortunately, `gulp-imagemin` seems to perform very poorly on compressing `*.jpg` images. I've managed to save 10kb on `.jpg` files that weighed ~300kb before I run the compression task. This was regardless of the `optimizationLevel` being set to 7 (the highest value).

When I saved the same image as 'optimized for web' in GIMP, its size was reduced by ~50%.

Why is `gulp-imagemin` so ineffective, and how I can effectively compress my images in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [imagemin-jpeg-recompress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-jpeg-recompress)?

Comment: Big improvement!! Thanks!